# Clear console on restart in nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I want to clear the console when nodemon restarts due to changes. But I also want to see error messages when my application crashes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the package.json (and replace server.js with the desired file) :

```
"scripts": {
  "start:dev": "nodemon --exec 'npm run dev'",
  "dev": "cls && node server.js"
}
```

Nodemon will watch for changes and will run the dev script on restart. The dev script clears the console and starts the Node.js application.